# Mqtt input with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, mqtt, iot

I recently installed the mqtt logstash plugin.

I am just using it like this on my localhost. I have a mosquito server running and i can publish topics and messages and i can subscribe to them and see the messages.

But when i want to get these messages as input in logstash something is going wrong.
I am just using the filter like this (the default values are all ok).

```
input {
    mqtt {      
     topic => "Temp"                
}
```

But i am getting this error message every time i publish a message to the topic Temp.

```
    2018-10-29T13:22:37,248][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:test
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Mqtt topic=>"Temp", id=>"2e42558ecbc14af5b8d3bbf6243a987cd9accfa6ba94d9802a86bed16bf90958",
  enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_1442bf51-53fb-43d1-a09c-48b29c870f66",
  enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, mqttHost=>"localhost", port=>1883, ssl=>false, client_id=>"logstash-mqtt-inputd42q", clean_session=>true, qos=>0>
  Error: Direct event field references (i.e. event['field']) have been disabled in favor of using event get and set methods (e.g. event.get('field')).
  Please consult the Logstash 5.0 breaking changes documentation for more details.
  Exception: NoMethodError
  Stack: C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/event.rb:43:in `method_missing'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-mqtt-0.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/mqtt.rb:63:in `block in run'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-codec-plain-3.0.6/lib/logstash/codecs/plain.rb:35:in `decode'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-mqtt-0.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/mqtt.rb:62:in `block in run'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/mqtt-0.5.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:405:in `block in get'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/mqtt-0.5.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:437:in `block in get_packet'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1292:in `loop'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/mqtt-0.5.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:435:in `get_packet'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/mqtt-0.5.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:404:in `get'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-mqtt-0.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/mqtt.rb:61:in `run'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:409:in `inputworker'
C:/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:403:in `block in start_input'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had installed the wrong plugin, you should use logstash-input-paho-mqtt.

This was my new input,

```
input { 
   mqtt {
   host => "localhost"
   port => 1883
   topic => "Temp"
   qos => 2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following section of the log seems to imply that the plugin is targeting a version before Logstash 5.0

```
Error: Direct event field references (i.e. event['field']) have been disabled in favor of using event get and set methods (e.g. event.get('field')).
  Please consult the Logstash 5.0 breaking changes documentation for more details.
  Exception: NoMethodError
```

It would appear that Logstash changed it's API at v5.0 and is no longer compatible with the plugin.